# NotFoundHttpException error when user types / in dynamic route

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel 5.3 i have a problem with my route (`web.php`) file. When the user sets the variable `$url` as "www.website.com" everything is OK, but if he types "http://​www.website.com" the parameter is being cut by '/' and an error is displayed. How to overcome this problem?

```
Route::get('/result/{url}', function($url){
  return view('result', ['url'=>$url]);
});
```

Comment: you have to encode the your url as `/` is treated as a separator

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/5WIT5 It looks like encoding doesn't helped. I encoded it using     `$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#form').submit(function() {

      var parameter = $('#url-input').val();
        parameter = (encodeURIComponent(parameter));

      window.location = "/result/" + parameter;
      return false; // return false to cancel form action
  });

});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing, it appears that Laravel decodes the url and treats `%2f` as `/` leading to the 404 error you get.

The workaround is to change the route definition to allow all chars in the parameter. Here is what you need to change :

```
Route::get('/result/{url}', function($url){
  return view('result', ['url'=>$url]);
})->where('url', '.*'); // allows all chars in the `url` parameter
```

This `.*` constraint will allow this parameter to accept any character. The downside of this method is that this parameter needs to be the last one, since it eats all the forward slashes and you won't be able to delimit any other route parameters.

Comment: Super it works. Question for future reference - can I theoretically write a complex regex replacing '.*'  so that I could add other route parameters?

Comment: yes, you can put any regex you want in there but that would be quite hard to separate a url from the other parameters

Answer (score 0):

As `/` in `http://www.website.com` separates url you can't use it as resource in url. you can remove `http://` from url by creating function which explodes url:

```
function explodeURLIfNeeded($url) {
    $url = end(explode('/', $url));
    return $url;
}
```